# Exception thrown on formSingleSelect macro freemarker.

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have this spring macro

```
[@spring.formSingleSelect path="discoveryProjectDetailsBean.discoveryProjectBean.dataSource" options="dataSources" /]
```

it throws exception 
`freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected collection or sequence. options evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 227, column 20 in spring.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:135)`

this happens because it cannot interpret the dataSource list as sequence.

any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown box - from Spring MVC model / context to form using freemarker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433510/dropdown-box-from-spring-mvc-model-context-to-form-using-freemarker)

Comment: yes it is, I found the question after I posted this one I also referenced it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I never found harder question that this, this exception above happened as the `dataSource` list I was trying to set as options list wasn't pure string list. all the options list to be passed to the `@spring.formSingleSelect` I also found another reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433510/dropdown-box-from-spring-mvc-model-context-to-form-using-freemarker)
      with a case just like mine code snippet of the working tag I am using now is below.

```
[@spring.bind "dataSources"/]     
[@spring.formSingleSelect "discoveryProjectDetailsBean.discoveryProjectBean.dataSource" dataSources "disabled='disabled' multiple='multiple' class='singleList' onchange='checkValidations()'" /]
```

I hope this would help somebody