# Freemarker: Create dropdown field and set its value and option from Map's key/value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

How would I create a dropdown field in freemarker template? Dropdown options and values will be passed from a map. Here is the map passing from **Controller**:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> codeTable = new HashMap<String,Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> codeTableValues = new HashMap<String,String>();
        codeTableValues.put("1", "US");
        codeTableValues.put("2", "UK");
        codeTableValues.put("3", "India");
        codeTableValues.put("4", "Ireland");
        codeTableValues.put("5", "Germany");
        codeTable.put("country", codeTableValues);
```

For freemarker I came across `spring.ftl` and trying to use `formSingleSelect` but can't get my head around it. **FTL** code:

```
<#elseif field.@type="select">
                <@spring.bind "codeTable.country" />
                <@spring.formSingleSelect "country", codeTable.country, "" />
            </#if>
```

**Exception**

```
FreeMarker template error: Method public org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException threw an exception when invoked on org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext object "org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@1479ef9" with arguments of types [java.lang.String,]. See cause exception. The failing instruction (FTL stack trace): ---------- ==> #assign status = springMacroRequestCo... [in template "spring.ftl" in macro "bind" at line 74, column 17] #else [in template "spring.ftl" in macro "bind" at line 73, column 9] @spring.bind "codeTable.country" [in template "index.ftl" at line 31, column 33] #elseif field.@type = "select" [in template "index.ftl" at line 30, column 25]
```

Comment: If you want to increase your chances to get an answer, you should copy-paste that error message without losing all the line-breaks. Also, it's `@spring.bind` that fails (so maybe your question could be more specific), but you haven't included the cause exception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured out that why `option` is getting failed. But I could not find any example where Map has been used to create a dropdown field. Can you please help me with that part?

Comment: Plus the only spring.formSingleSelect implementation I found was from this SO question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433510/dropdown-box-from-spring-mvc-model-context-to-form-using-freemarker?rq=1

Comment: Well, I'm not a Spring user, I just know FreeMarker. Looking at `spring.ftl` I see that the 2nd parameter meant to be a `Map`. So if what you pass in there is a `Map`, it should work. So what's the error message now?

Comment: Will try it on Monday and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Build dropdown using `spring.formSingleSelect`. Assume that you have a Bean named `Vacccine`.

```
public class Vaccine {

    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String companyName;
    
    private Integer country;
    
    // Getter & Setter

}
```

And Country Map like below...

```
Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<>();
countryMap.put("1", "US");
countryMap.put("2", "UK");
countryMap.put("3", "India");
countryMap.put("4", "Ireland");
countryMap.put("5", "Germany");
```

Then you can bind Country Map like below...

```
<@spring.formSingleSelect  'Vaccine.country', countryMap, 'class="form-control" ' />
```